# an array of map objects in qml (javascript)

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, pyside6

I'm trying to save object maps using javascript array in qml

```
property var arrayData: []
onClicked: {                          
  arrayData.push(mapData)
}
```

and when I print the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
  print("\t ******** " + i + " ********")
  for(const [key, value] of arrayData[i].entries()) {                        
    print(key + " : " + value)
  }
  print("\t ******** " + i + " ********")
}
```

terminal:

```
  qml:     ******** 1 ********q
  qml: D:/V 0.0.53.34/data.csv : PaSide_dBm,Toa Main
  qml:     ******** 0 ********
  qml:     ******** 1 ********
  qml: D:/V 0.0.53.34/data.csv : PaSide_dBm,ToaMain
  qml:     ******** 1 ********
```

when i add a new map to the array the other maps will change too
meaning the first element and second element are not the same
i don't know why ):
so how can i create an array of maps?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's mapData? Do you keep adding the same mapData every time you click? A [mre] would help.

Comment: that is a Map object (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_maps.asp) no any time i click it pushes a new element but when i print the elements all of them are the same